# How to run analytic in spark?

Tags: java, apache-spark, jar, analytics

I'm new to Spark. I'm still learning it. I have questions that would like opinion.

1. I have to prepare jar file for the analytic method that should be suitable to run as spark job.

   - is it necessary for jar to be executable / runnable?
   - Can I prepare jar as library with few methods
2. For my case,I have input and output of the analytic

Here, can I pass input json and get output json in the spark?

What are the steps?

Any help or links to read will be helpful?

Answer (score 0):

1. Your first question basically asked how to run Spark with java API. Here is some code I think you'll find useful

`SparkLauncher launcher = new SparkLauncher()
                setAppName(config.getString("appName"))
                .setSparkHome(sparkHomePath)
                .setAppResource(pathToYourJar)
                .setMaster(masterUrl)
                .setMainClass(fullNameOfMainClass);`
You might need to add `launcher.addJar(...)`

Create an instance of SparkAppHandle.Listener
`SparkAppHandle handle = launcher.startApplication(sparkJobListener);`

*"can I pass input json and get output json in the spark?"*
If you wish to read a JSON as the input you can follow the instructions in this [link](https://roizaig.blogspot.com/2019/10/spark-how-to-read-json-file.html)